# AC control coil relay

Tags: ac, relay

Is there a type of relay where the control coil can operate from a 220/240 VAC signal? I don't want to convert my existing signal from AC to DC. Are there any special search techniques to find parts with this specification?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, Be more kind, in cases like this the user is visiting from another site and this may be a standard way to post there.

Comment: @Kortuk - I don't think Olin should be nicer to others than he is to us. No privileges! ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh, Ha. Well he is working his hardest to compete with a certain user for the most total received flags. He is only 75% of the way there so far, but trying hard.

Comment: @Kortuk: People should *think* a bit about what they are asking.  *"Can anybody tell me ..."* is not what he wants to know, so it's dumb to ask that.  People aren't going to learn to ask properly if we let them get away with asking badly.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, Yes, And I understand you making a point of that but statements like "duh." at the end are just being sharper then needed. I am glad your quality standards are high but when it is a users first post allow your PID loop to take time to build up to frustrated comments.

Comment: @Olin - If someone in the street asks me "Can you tell me the time?" I say what time it is, not "Yes". :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look.

1. go to the [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com) website
2. type "relays" as keyword to look for
3. you get a list of related product categories, select "Power relays" (if that's what you need)
4. filter in the listed items for all relays with a coil voltage between 220V AC and 240V AC
5. click apply filters
6. enjoy the list of 629 applicable relays.

[This one](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Phoenix%20Contact%20PDFs/2961451.pdf) requires the least power to activate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, lot's of people can tell you that.

You didn't ask, but others may be interested to know that such relays exist, in fact are common.  Those that wish to find such relays should do a search on the Mouser, DigiKey, or other web sites that list lots of parts.  I haven't actually done such a search myself, but I am confident various models will be easily found with a small amount of effort.

You could also look around on the web sites of suspected manufacturers, like Tycho, Potter and Brumfield, etc.